# How to get a message during video player pause event?

Tags: javascript, html, video, dom-events, media

I have an html file, where I want to control the pause/play of the video player through the video player. Means, when I click the play button in the video player it pauses, and it should display an alert saying the video is  paused. The html checkpause button is working fine, now how to do it with video player? I've written the below code, but the alert is not popping up. What is going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>     
<body>          
<center>
<button onclick="enableLoop()" type="button">Enable loop</button>    
<button onclick="disableLoop()" type="button">Disable loop</button>    
<button onclick="checkLoop()" type="button">Check loop status</button>    
<button onclick="checkended()" type="button">Check end status</button>    
<button onclick="checkpause()" type="button">Check pause status</button>    
<br />         
<video id="video" controls="controls" >    
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" >    
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" >    
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.    
</video>    
</center>    
<script>
var media_events = new Array();
media_events["play"] = 0;
media_events["pause"] = 0;

document._video = document.getElementById("video");
//document._video.autoplay=true;
document._video.load();
//document._video.play();
//alert ("Video started");

function init(){
    alert("at init function");
//init_events();
    //alert("Value of key in init_events is:" + key + "");
    for (key in media_events) { 
    //alert("Value of key in init_events is:" + key + "");
    document._video.addEventListener(key, capture, false);
    }
    var tbody = document.getElementById("events");
    for (key in media_events) { 
        alert("Status of Video is :" + key + "");
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

//Media Events.

function init_events() {
    alert("Value of key in init_events is:" + key + "");
    for (key in media_events) { 
    document._video.addEventListener(key, capture, false);
    }
   for (key in media_events) {  
        //var output = document.createElement("");
        //output.textContent += "Key value is:" + key + "";
        alert("Final status of Video is :" + key + "");
    }
}



function capture(event) {
    //alert("At capture func and key value is " + key + "");
    media_events[event.type] = media_events[event.type] + 1;
    alert("Media Event type is" + media_events[event.type] + "");
    for (key in media_events) { 
    alert("At capture func and key value is " + key + "");
    var e = document.getElementById("e_" + key);
    //alert("Value of e is:" + e + "");
    if (e) {
        e.innerHTML = media_events[key];
        if (media_events[key] > 0) {
            e.className = "true";
            alert("Value is " + key + "");
        }
        else{
            alert("Value in else is " + key + "");
            e.className = "false";
            alert("Value is key in 'e' else is " + key + "");
        }
    }
    else{
    alert("Value of key in else is " + key + "");
    }
    
}
}

function enableLoop()    
  {     
  document._video.loop=true;    
  document._video.load();    
  } 

function disableLoop()    
  {     
  document._video.loop=false;    
  document._video.load();    
  } 

function checkLoop()    
  {     
  alert(document._video.loop);    
  } 

function checkended()    
  {     
  alert(document._video.ended);    
  }
  
  function checkpause()    
  {     
  if (document._video.paused) { alert("video is in pause"); }
  else{
  alert("Video is not paused");}    
  }

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than reacting to the event that's been triggered in "capture" you seem to be looping through all the possible events and reacting to them.

this sample shows a simple, lightweight way of responding to the different events - I'd suggest modifying it to track the play/pause flags https://gist.github.com/3718414

```
function capture(e) {
if (e.type == "pause") {
    document._video.paused = true;
} else if (e.type == "play") {
    document._video.paused = false;
}
    checkpause();
}
```